# Parsing boto3 invoke_endpoint response from AWS SageMaker

Tags: parsing, boto3

I have a Sagemaker endpoint that I can infer to from boto3 client and get response.

Per [boto3 doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-runtime.html), the `Body` of the response result is a `Byte` object `StreamingBody` type. I convert it to a dictionary

```
    response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, Body=json.dumps(data))
response_body = response['Body']
dict_response = response_body.read().decode('utf-8')
print(dict_response)
```

The above code gives me a response like below (stripped down for this post)

I need to retrieve the array from the "floatVal" key. How do I do that?

```
{
  "outputs": {
    "score": {
      "dtype": "DT_FLOAT",
      "floatVal": [
        0.00012408883776515722,
        ...........
        -0.8316119909286499,
        -0.24423488974571228
      ],
      "tensorShape": {
        "dim": [
          {
            "size": "1"
          },
          {
            "size": "1024"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "modelSpec": {
    "version": "1",
    "name": "generic_model",
    "signatureName": "serving_default"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually the `dict_response` is not really a `dictionary` here, rather a `string` type. So I had to convert the `dict_response` to an actual dictionary and then I could  retrieve the `floatVal` key.

Updated code

```
response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, Body=json.dumps(data))
response_body = response['Body']
response_str = response_body.read().decode('utf-8')
response_dict = eval(response_str)
print(response_dict['outputs']['score']['floatVal'])
```

Comment: json.loads(response_str) is probably safer than eval()?